# how to upload videos in html from folder & from youtube and how they will be shown like pictures are shown after doing thumnails

Tags: html

I have one video file inmy system I want it to attach it on my html page.I want same thing with youtube videos also.I want that when i open my html form this video appear as like same as pictures are seen at thumnails.means i dont want only links..I tried stackoverflow links but no one is telling from starting .I am telling u frankly i dont know even making a link of my sytem video file in html form,..I can make links for image,files etc but for video si dont know.So plz guide ..

1.HOw to make a simple link of video file which is in my system drive.
2.HOw this video will be displayed like pictures are displayed at thumbnails
3.How to upload youtube videos(not want only link)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a video file then you need an image to represent your thumbnail. To create a link that will allow someone to download the video is as simple as:

```
 <a href="url of your video file">
     <img src="url of the thumbnail image"/>
 </a>
```

Then the user will see the thumbnail image and when they click on it they will get the video. If you wish to embed the video in a player you can select the player of choice such as [FlowPlayer](http://flowplayer.org/) or any of a million others.

You question about you-tube I assume you mean to embed you-tube videos on yout site. If that is the case visit the video on you-tube and there is an embed text box on the page with the code that you must copy and paste into your site.

---

EDIT:
The FlowPlayer that I linked to (not an endorsement) has a page that describes in great detail how to do what you are asking for [here](http://flowplayer.org/documentation/installation/index.html). If you follow each step then you will get exactly what you envision.

---

Another Edit:

To play a particular file format you need to use an appropriate player. I do not know all the players but you want to make sure that the format you use is popular enough so that users do not have to download special plugins just to see your video.

If you visit the [DivX](http://labs.divx.com/node/14711) website you will find their embeddable player that can play mkv files on your website. They have a [Code Generator](http://labs.divx.com/WebPlayerCodeGenerator) that produces the code that you will use to embed the player on your site.

As for various options like starting in pause mode etc you will have to read the documentation of the player that you use to see what options they allow.

Comment: most of the time i have seen that in a website a video file is diplaying in thumbnail and now this file is in pause state and when u click on the center for play it get started playing without reloading page..i dont know how to introduce a player into above link plz tell also this in coading

Comment: I follow your refernced link.Wav it is wonderfull..Thanks man.But still i am facing some problems...

1.I am not able to play videos of size approx 500 mb like a movie like 3-idiots.mkv or veer.wav etc..It Is able to play only .flv files..So how i can play other files also...

2.When page loads automatically video start playing i wnat that it come in pause mode.Means when user clik on play button only then video plays..How i can do this...

3.I want that this player window comes in right side.I know align="right" will be used but where it will be used.Plz also tell me this thing

Comment: ok fine i got your pint but tell me one thing i am using flowplayer for videos but i wnat that more than one videos can be embbed on page..i tried but not succeeded .I wirte my video file path with A tag with previous vieo file but it i snot working.Will u tell me plz how i can do this.

Answer (score 0):

you an download ny video from youtube and these videos are in .flv format so why u are taking tension.Just use them frequently.And for youtube videos u do not need to use flowplay just add youtube video url and add object that will be given in that page just above the related video..

But me too do not how to allign it on right side or in middle of the page..Can anybody tell..